# Error 210002 with XCode + SVN

Tags: svn, xcode, version-control

I'm trying to use the built-in Subversion server on OS X per [Apple's instruction](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/server/subversionwithxcode3.html) I'm trying to use SVN through SSH and not apache

It's not working out though. When I try to configure the repository, I get the following error:

```
Error: 210002 (Network connection closed unexpectedly) Description: Connection closed unexpectedly
```

As a sanity check, I tried doing an "svn list" from the command line, and it worked. And, I'm using the same URL structure as on the configuration screen. From the command line, it works!

Any suggestions on how to further troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Which version of Xcode on which version of Mac OS X?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179112/error-210002-with-xcode-svn

Comment: Er, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506025/xcode-and-subversion-error-210002-but-connection-ok

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414747/subversion-has-stopped-working-with-snow-leopard-install

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, but what happened was I rebuilt a server and the file called "known_hosts" had the old server setup of that same machine in my user account, in "~/.ssh",  I trashed the known_hosts file and went to terminal, and re-ssh-ed.  After that everything worked as normal.

Hope that helps,

Laters...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I needed to delete and recreate my login keychain. Once I added the password again for one svn repository in the XCode Repositories Configure panel (which shows the XCode Preferences Repositories panel), clicked Always Allow for the keychain access prompt, and then clicked Apply in the XCode Repositories Configure panel where I added the password, then SVN access for all my projects worked again.

Sorry for bumping an old thread, but I hope this helps someone who has the "Error: 210002 (Network connection closed unexpectedly) Description: (null)" problem when trying to use SVN for an XCode project.

I'm using XCode 3.2.1 (64-bit).

Best regards,

Piesia

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy-to-miss point about configuring XCode and Subversion/SCM running on the same computer. For it to work, you must go into Settings->Sharing and enable "Remote Login" by checking the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here’s how I fixed this (on Mac OS X, but fix should work on any client)

This particular issue arises when you are using a non-standard port (let’s say 12001 for sake of example) for your SSH server.

Apparently the SVN client experiences syntax errors when given a port address on a command line like this one:

svn list svn+ssh://username@domainname.com:12001/home/username/svn/myproject

So, to fix this, you need to create a client-side config file for SSH like this:

cd ~
cd .ssh
vi config (create a config file like the one that follows)
:w
:q

Config file located in ~/.ssh/config:

Host domain.com
User username
Port 12001

Then, issue your svn+ssh command WITHOUT the port like this:

svn list svn+ssh://username@domain.com/home/username/svn/myproject

That’s it!

Hope that helps.
Rick