# Subversion has stopped working with snow leopard install

Tags: svn, osx-snow-leopard

With the install of snow leopard access to subversion has stopped working, any one know how I can fix it?

When I click on my repository I get

list svn+ssh//yoda@192.168.0.6/library/subversion/respository/apps
Error 210002 (Network connection closed unexpectedly Description: (null)

Any help would be very gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be connecting through SSH. First try to manually ssh into the remote server.

```
ssh -vvv yoday@192.168.0.6
```

Since it's a local address, I assume it's another mac computer and had been upgraded to snow leopard as well, changing the machine fingerprint for SSH, and it's closing the link for your safety (man in the middle attack).

Try to remove `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Ah yes remote log in was disabled!  Thank you!