# TextMate SVN commit window

Tags: svn, textmate, textmatebundles

I upgraded from Mac OS X 10.4.11 to 10.6.3. I am using TextMate in both versions and as far as I know, both TextMates have the same settings, although they are different versions.

In my old Mac TextMate's SVN bundle works perfectly. In my new Mac, SVN bundle does not pull up the commit window when it is invoked (Ctrl-Shift-A, Commit)

What could be wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try to track down which part of your tool chain is failing. 
Open a 'terminal' and check whether subversion is working from the command line. If subversion works fine, TextMate might have a configuration issue. You may check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414747/subversion-has-stopped-working-with-snow-leopard-install) as well.

Comment: yah ive tracked evreything down, everything's in the right place. svn is working only the commit window does not show up.